# Show all database contents in a ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to Show all database contents in a List View in Android Studio, I expect to see 3 rows that each row contains "name, family and ID" , but I see a comlex of package name and some other characters as follws:

com.google.www.hmdbtest01.Person@529e71b4

com.google.www.hmdbtest01.Person@529e7238

com.google.www.hmdbtest01.Person@529e7298

if I have more rows in my database, I will see more lines like above in the output.

my codes are as follow:

```
public class ListOfData extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_of_data);

    ListView  list = findViewById(R.id.list1);
    HmDbManager01 db= new HmDbManager01(this);
    ArrayList personList = db.getAll();
    ArrayAdapter<ArrayList> arrayList = new ArrayAdapter<ArrayList>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, personList);

    list.setAdapter(arrayList);
}
}
```

db.getAll() is as follows:

```
public ArrayList<Person> getAll(){
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor= sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_person", null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
ArrayList<Person> allData = new ArrayList<>();

if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()){
        Person p1 = new Person();
        p1.pID=cursor.getString(0);
        p1.pName=cursor.getString(1);
        p1.pFamily=cursor.getString(2);
        allData.add(p1);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
}
cursor.close();
sqLiteDatabase.close();
return allData;
}
```

and, this is Person:

```
package com.google.www.hmdbtest01;
public class Person {
public String pID;
public String pName;
public String pFamily;
}
```

Let me know your comments on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

arrayListAdapter will convert your personList to list of string

change like it:

```
    ArrayList<String> persons = new ArrayList<String>();
    personList.forEach(personModel -> {
        persons.add(personModel.name + " " + personModel.lastName + " " + personModel.id);
    });
    ArrayAdapter<ArrayList> arrayList = new ArrayAdapter<ArrayList>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, persons);
```

Comment: thanks mahdi, but your solution makes a string but I need a table.

Comment: So you must implement your custom array adapter

Comment: I have used Simple_list_item_1 as an adapter. Is it suitable for this table? Your recommendation for an Adapter is appreciated.

Comment: simple adapter is not suitable therefor i suggest you to read more from [here] (https://medium.com/mindorks/custom-array-adapters-made-easy-b6c4930560dd)

Comment: what is personModel in your codes above? I see an error with "personModel.name" and also for other variables: personModel.lastName and personModel.id